# Radius of Convergence of a Series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

How would I find the radius of convergence of the following series?

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)}
$$

The ratio test and root test are inconclusive, so I think I have to use the definition of the radius of convergence

$$\frac{1}{R}=\limsup|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

I have been told that the $n$-th coefficient of this series is not $$\frac{(-1)^n}{n}.$$

I am not sure what exactly I should equate to $|a_n|$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|z|\gt 1$, then $\frac{|z|^{n(n+1)}}n$ does not converge to $0$, and when $|z|\lt 1$, $\sum_n |z|^{n(n+1)} $ is convergent, so the radius of convergence is $1$.

Indeed, the $n$-th coefficient is not $\frac{(-1)^n}n$ as if we write the series into the form $\sum_k b_kx^k$, we have $b_{k(k+1)}=\frac{(-1)^k}k$ and $b_n=0$ if $n$ is not of the form $k(k+1)$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Ok so say we want to find out if the series diverges for z = -1, z = i, how would we go about it?

Comment: Notice that $n(n+1)$ is an even integer.